# Is it possible to upgrade the graphics card of a laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, toshiba-laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

Can I upgrade the graphics card of the Toshiba Satellite S50T to Nvidia or anything more powerful than the stock AMD Radeon?

I haven't purchased it yet, although I'm hoping to in the next month.

The laptop's specs:

- i7-451U 2Ghz CPU
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- 1TB HDD + 8 GB SSD hybrid
- 15.6" Full HD Touch display
- 2 GB AMD Radeon™ R7 M260** dedicated VRAM

Answer (score 4):

Knowing laptop hardware in general, it's highly unlikely that you would be able to upgrade a the graphics card in that laptop. Since the laptop is so new, I couldn't find any disassembly guides for it, but I can say with certainty that the level of disassembly required to replace a laptop GPU will void your warranty and won't be cost or time-effective. You would be better off buying a laptop with higher specs to begin with.

Here's a list of the issues you would face:

1. Newer laptops are getting increasingly harder to disassemble successfully, especially thinner models.
2. You will void your warranty.
3. Most laptop GPUs are soldered to the motherboard and are essentially impossible to remove in a reasonable way.
4. Your choices for an upgrade will be limited even if you do succeed in getting your laptop apart - there's no guarantee that any graphics chip will fit in your laptop or that you'll be able to purchase a suitable one for a reasonable price.

Also, I would look at some more reviews before you buy - the ones I saw online all appeared to be under three stars.